# how to set a string to Animted.Value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to set a string instead of number to Animted.Value ?

`React.useRef(new Animated.Value('15%')).current;` Like this ?

Comment: You cant, `Animated` only take a constant number and not `%` one. You could though assign `Dimensions` change to resign the value though.

Comment: You could just give the number of the percentage and interpolate as a percentage https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#interpolation